# Popping sound after any audio playing

Tags: sound, 20.04, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I have Ubuntu 20.04 together with Windows10. It's about one week that when I playing any sounds through my speakers, after about 10s I hear a pop sound from the right speaker. Even when I change the volume or I open just the sound settings, I can hear that annoying sound. After some searches, I got [this](https://superuser.com/a/1493101/1135730) solution. This worked for when I use a battery and AC power is not plugged in. But I'm not sure that this was the correct solution. I think it is a temporary solution.
After that, when the AC power is connected or even with the battery, I don't hear that popping sound. But when shutdown, restart or suspend my system, I can hear that sound.
And also when I use HDMI to connect my Monitor with its speaker, I can again hear the sound even with AC power after and before playing any sound.
On my Windows also even with AC power with or without HDMI, I can hear the popping sound even when no sound playing, periodically.
My 1st question is that if [this](https://superuser.com/a/1493101/1135730) solution is correct.
and 2nd is how to disable that sound forever (even in shutdown).
and the 3rd question is that sound natural on the shutdown? because I don't hear that sound about one week ago and more.

Comment: In the solution you linked, there is also information how to make the change persistent (ie. "disable the sound forever"). Just try it if it works. It won't harm your system. You can always return to previous values if it doesn't work.

Comment: @raj With that solution for make all things persistene, when I plug the AC power in and plug it out, both files return to their default values and also the popping sound at the shutdown or restart or suspending wont be fixed! What should I do for fixing that sound on shutdown?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` is returning to default value after you edited it? What makes it do so?

Comment: Yes exactly correct! I dont know what makes it do so. Just after a restart or after plug in and out the AC power it returns to its defaults.

Comment: Then try the solution from there: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230833/annoying-click-popping-sound-on-ubuntu-20-04 . It uses the file `/etc/modprobe.d/audio_disable_powersave.conf` instead of  `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

Comment: @raj that link solve persistent problem but still I have the problem when shut down, restart or suspend my laptop (both on battery or AC power)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116441/discussion-between-emad-helmi-and-raj).