# Weird sound from speakers on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, sound

A month ago I installed 20.04 from scratch after using 16.04 for severl years and I noticed a weird sound coming from my speakers. It started right from the very beginning after I installed clean 20.04. I've attached the sound below. It happens whenever there is no sound coming out from the speakers, that is when I don't listen any music, etc. When I stop the sound, it starts again after around 5 seconds. I am using these GX Gaming speakers https://www.amazon.co.uk/Genius-SW-G2-1-1250-Channel-Speaker/dp/B007IZRQES.

Sound:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R2nWZXvooc6K2L1sVY3WKGKmE9QuatPD/view?usp=sharing

```
uname -a
Linux Home 5.13.0-35-generic #40~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 7 09:18:32 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Pulseaudio driver

```
$ apt-cache show pulseaudio
Package: pulseaudio
Architecture: amd64
Version: 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13
Multi-Arch: foreign
Priority: optional
Section: sound
Origin: Ubuntu
```

What could be the issue and how can I fix it?

***UPDATE***

My audio card details

```
$ lspci -v | grep -i -A7 audio 
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 33
    Memory at f7210000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev d0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
--
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GM204 High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at f7080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Comment: As I said, I didn't have this problem on Ubuntu 16.04 so I don't know how this would be a hardware issue.

Comment: What is the audio card?  Maybe power_save issue like https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230833/annoying-click-popping-sound-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: @AndrewLowther I updated my answer to show my audio card. Your link worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The fix for this issue is to disable power save on the card. The link suggested by Andrew Lowther above provides the solution.

[Annoying click/popping sound on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230833/annoying-click-popping-sound-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score 0):

Power save is good! Try to avoid disabling it ;) There is a probable alternate solution, from https://askubuntu.com/a/1399239/817790 that worked instantly for me. (probably improved audio quality, too)

Kernel version 5.13.0-37. (Use `uname -a` to check your kernel version.)

```bsh
sudo nano /etc/pulse/daemon.conf
```

Find the lines starting with

```
; default-sample-rate
; alternate-sample-rate
```

Remove the ; and change the values to 48000 so it looks like this:

```
default-sample-rate = 48000
alternate-sample-rate = 48000
```

Save the file, then restart pulse audio with

```
pulseaudio -k
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the solution posted by simlei, you can also try to change the buffer size by adjusting these settings to something like this:

```
default-fragments = 3
default-fragment-size-msec = 5
```

Where the effective latency is the product of the two.

The third solution (and I know you said your problems started right after you installed Ubuntu 20.04) is to plug the speakers into a separate power outlet (if you're using a power strip), so as to make sure they're not picking up any static from outside sources. (I had a really serious problem with this).