# Annoying click sound on Ubuntu 21.10 after kernel update

Tags: kernel, updates, pulseaudio, alsa

As said in the subject, an annoying click sound started to happen with my external soundcard after updating to new kernel.

It seems is not something unknown. Found this in this forum:

[Annoying click/popping sound on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1230833/1582367)

where the issue is linked with this confirmed bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-5.13/+bug/1966066

I followed the recomendation in the thread about editing sample rate in /etc/pulse/daemon.conf and it seems it have fixed the issue for most of my sound-related apps BUT Ardour. Ardour is going through ALSA and the click is there, affecting also recording.

My setup: Ubuntu 21.10 with updated kernel, Ardour 6, Behringer UM2. Everything worked smooth before kernel update.

Any suggestion is welcome (have not found anything specific related with the issue and ALSA), I have work to do :'(

Pablo

Comment: Did you add your own report to the existing bug reports? This is the best thing you can do to get the bug fixed faster.  In the meantime choose the older kernel when you boot.

Comment: Thanks Nmath. Overlooked both things, you are right. Will do.