# Sound bug: popping/cracking sound whenever there is any audio playback

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I have a brand new Ubuntu installation on a fairly old system. Getting the system to even start was a bit painful until I found [this helpful blog post](https://blog.le-vert.net/?p=24).

Anyway I'm typing from this machine running Ubuntu now and I have 3 audio outputs (I tried to take a screenshot of the settings - sound window with the drop-down menu for selecting output device but the screenshot key doesn't work unless the menu is closed. ):

- HSMI/DisplayPort 2 - GK104 HDMI Audio Controller
- Digital Output(S/PDIF) - Built-in audio
- Line Out - Built-in Audio

The first one outputs to my monitor through the HDMI cable and it works fine, as far as I can't tell

The second one I don't use, but it doesnt even stay selected - whenever I try to select it it just reverses to Line Out.

The third one outputs to my headphones, it's the one I use the most and where the problem occurs:

Whenever any audio is going to my headphones, popping/cracking sounds at seemingly random times and amplitudes appear at my monitor speakers. I'm not a native English speaker so I'm having a hard time figuring out how to explain it with words, so I recorded a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hRhV9zfVY3o)

In the video you can see that the output section of settings -> sound flickers more or less in sync with the popping.

Things I've tried to solve the issue with no luck:

[Annoying click/popping sound on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230833/annoying-click-popping-sound-on-ubuntu-20-04)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pdmy8dMWitg

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TjmHVgCSpQQ

I reverted all the changes suggested in the links above since they didn't work and I don't really know what else they do on the system

[PC specs (lshw output)](https://pastebin.com/N1auTTHM)

MoBo is a Asus RoG Maximus V gene running an i5-3750k and gfx card is a GTX660Ti.

Any help is appreciated but I won't be able to come back to this until tomorrow.
Ubuntu version is Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: I tried 

```sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends pulseaudio alsa-base alsa-utils```

followed by 

```sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends pulseaudio alsa-base alsa-utils```

and now I don't get any actual audio when I try to play something through my headphones, but the popping is still there...

Comment: You've not provided any product/release details; Ubuntu LTS releases offer two kernel stacks (*plus more OEM options for some hardware*) thus just using the other kernel stack choice (*which means different kernel modules which are commonly known as drivers get used*) can be a fix; but you've not provided any release details, thus this may or may not apply. Please be specific with details; what Ubuntu product are you asking about?

Comment: @guiverc sorry but I don't really understand what you said about kernel modules. I Just went to https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop, downloaded it to a pen-drive and installed it. Is there a terminal command that outputs the information you asked about?

Comment: Sorry I now see you mentioned Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.  I usually look for release details at the start; I saw 20.04 LTS in a pasted URL where `uname -r` will tell you 5.4 is the kernel if you're using 20.04 with the GA kernel stack, and 20.04 using the HWE kernel stack will say 5.15 for a fully updated system & 5.13 or something less for a system behind on upgrades & HWE kernel stack.  Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is currently 5.15 for both GA & HWE kernel stacks (server & *flavor* ISOs default to GA but desktop defaults to HWE).  Kernel stacks can't help a 22.04 LTS system yet as too new (*I'm ignoring OEM*)

Comment: Just to confirm:

`leonardo@Passaportout:~$ uname -r
5.15.0-40-generic`



I'll be sure to mention Ubuntu version and pc specs at the start of the post in the future

Comment: I reinstalled Ubuntu. The problem persists, and it's more pronounced now. So much that I was able to understand it better: what's actually happening is that Ubuntu constantly tries to change output device from LineOut to HDMI, but it (now somewhat) quickly reverts back to LineOut. The "popping" occurs when the audio output is changed.