# How to stop speaker random popping noise on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, 22.04, speakers

I have a PC with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS dual booting with Windows 10. After a fresh install of ubuntu I notice a random popping sound (very small but it's there) from my speaker (edifier r1280dbs).

It seems to happen whenever I open heavy apps (like microsoft teams), or when I login/logout of the system. But it can happen randomly too. I've searched intensively and most of the results I found say that the problem is in the power saving option of the sound card. I've follow the solutions here but none's working. [Annoying click/popping sound on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230833/annoying-click-popping-sound-on-ubuntu-20-04)
Please help me solve this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1266632/553502) worked for me.

1. Backup the existing PuseAudio config file: `sudo cp /etc/pulse/default.pa /etc/pulse/default.bak`
2. Edit the config file: `gedit admin:///etc/pulse/default.pa`
3. Hash out the entry load-module module-suspend-on-idle: `#load-module module-suspend-on-idle`
4. Save and close the config file
5. Restart PluseAudio: `systemctl restart --user pulseaudio`

Comment: Didn't work for me. Not sure what else to try. It keeps idling every time the volume is lower than a threshold.

Comment: @JakeOPJ - this could be an issue with your speakers, so you could try testing a different set of speakers.

Comment: it doesn't do it on Windows. There's a threshold somewhere that lets the service sleep when sound is too low.

Comment: @JakeOPJ [try reading here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Power_management#Audio).

Answer (score 0):

Because none of the solutions worked for me, and the speakers keep idling when the volume is low for a while, I found this hack works:

> play -q -r 48000 -n -t alsa -b 16 -c 2 synth sin 10 vol -10dB

I just play this inaudible (for me) sound all the time and they never idle.

Answer (score 0):

[note: you need to be root for this].

Open file in terminal:

sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

Add the following line at the bottom of the page:

options snd-hda-intel power_save=0 power_save_controller=N

save and reboot.