# Annoying "noise", "scratching" while wathing video or listening audio files on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, virtualbox, firefox, pulseaudio, alsa

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1 on VirtualBox on Windows 11 on my laptop for 8 month already. Recently i noticed some annoying "noise", "scratching" and freezing of sound while watching videos or listening audio files on Ubuntu. I tried recommendations [How to stop speaker random popping noise on Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1421892/how-to-stop-speaker-random-popping-noise-on-ubuntu-22-04)
and [Annoying click/popping sound on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230833/annoying-click-popping-sound-on-ubuntu-20-04),
but none of them helped.

The noise is random and intermittent.

I used the command `free`:

```
                  total           used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
    Mem:         4005116     1599548      994768       71588     1410800     2111096
    Swap:        3317756           0     3317756
```

I do not know how to share audio samples here. It would helped a lot if I could.

Method 1. I tried using this answer.

[image]

I used  `cat /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save` and got this as a result

```
cat: /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save: No such file or directory
```

Method 2. Then I used this.

[image]

I ran this command:

```
sudo nano /etc/pulse/daemon.conf
```

and tried to change the values of sample rates,but I don't know how to execute it so I'm stuck like this.

[image]

Method 3. After that I followed here, did the command and got this:

[image]

```
     sudo sed -i 's/--\["session.suspend-timeout-seconds"\] = 5/\["session.suspend-timeout-seconds"\] = 0/' /usr/share/wireplumber/main.lua.d/50-alsa-config.lua
        systemctl restart --user pipewire.service
        [sudo] password for :
        sed: can't read /usr/share/wireplumber/main.lua.d/50-alsa-config.lua: No such file or directory
```

Still nothing helped.

Comment: Have you wiggled every connection? Moved some new electrical device too close? Is the noise constant, intermittent, or random? How much memory, how much swap? Use the  terminal command `free`.  Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Don't use Add Comment.

Comment: Telling us which remote procedures (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages **you** got on **your system**. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.