# HDMI output sound cuts in after period of dormant sound

Tags: sound, suspend, hdmi, monitor

I have my speakers [Logitech Z333](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/products/speakers/z333-speaker-system-subwoofer.980-001203.html) plugged in to my [LG 32GK650F-B](https://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-32GK650F-B-gaming-monitor) monitor, and when sound isn't active for a period of time it take some time before sound kicks in to the speakers. I notice slack notifications cut in half way in(the last end of a slack tone) or music cuts in late or delays when hitting play. It seems like there is some sort of sleep function after a minute of no sound. I had a similar problem with my built in intel sound output device and fixed it with this posting [Annoying click/popping sound on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230833/annoying-click-popping-sound-on-ubuntu-20-04).

I'm wondering if there is an equivalent setting for hdmi outputs.
This is the pactl list short sinks output of the hdmi stereo:

```
9   alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   RUNNING
```

In sound settings the output device is called **HDMI/DisplayPort - TU104 HD Audio Controller**