Why this sound?
I have Ubuntu on my laptop and it turns out that every time a video or audio is played, a loud sound like a beep starts for an estimated time and it can vary, can someone help me find a solution, I would greatly appreciate it.

Please be more detailed, if possible by recording a clip of the issue.

Possibly related issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230833/annoying-click-popping-sound-on-ubuntu-20-04
